How to induce Haar measure on coset space?
Question: Given a left Haar measure on a locally compact Hausdorff group $G$, how to induce a measure on $G/H$ for some closed subgroup $H$?
I happened to see Selberg trace formula in number theory, but I have little knowledge in analysis (only basic knowledge on measure).
In the statement of Selberge trace formula, it defines $a_\varGamma^G(\gamma)$ to be the volume of $\varGamma^\gamma\backslash G^\gamma$, where $\varGamma^\gamma$ and $G^\gamma$ are centralizers. I think the volume is induced by the Haar measure of $G^\gamma$, as a closed subgroup of $G$. But I can't see a way to do so.
Any suggestions please?
P.S. Actually, I'm not interested in the detailed proof of the existence, if it is too complicated. I'm just wondering how to define such a induced measure, or equivalently, the relation between the original measure and the induced measure.

I am a bit out of my comfort zone, but if $\pi:G\to G/H$ is the natural projection, and $U\subseteq G/H$ some subset, can you simply study $\pi^{-1}(U)$ to define whether $U$ is measurable, and what its measure is (when exists).

@JyrkiLahtonen I think you may define $\bar\mu(U)=\mu(\pi^{-1}(U))/\mu(H)$ when $H$ is compact, but it fails when $H$ is not, since $\mu(H)=\infty$ in this case.

Quite. I had just started worrying about that :-)

This measure (as a Radon measure) only exists, if the modular functions of $G$ and $H$ agree (which is the case for $H$ being a centraliser). You find a complete proof of this and the trace formula in Deitmar/Echterhoff: Principles of Harmonic Analysis.
